# Beagleboard Bare-Metal DVI-D output

Tags: c, arm, beagleboard, omap

I have a very simple "bare-metal" build on a Beagleboard xM Rev. C board (thanks to all the help on Stackoverflow!). BTW, this is in "C". I'm able to view data over the serial connector.

My question: does anyone have any idea how to drive the on-board DVI-D connection from "bare-metal"?? I realize that I need to essentially write the "driver", but does anyone have some code that I could look at and start with?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried [the Linux driver](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/gpu/drm/tilcdc/)? Possibly a bit complex to start with, but maybe worth a look if you can pick the hardware bits out of all the Linux-specific stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That is some heavy-reading.